# location.reload() in ajax for a button is messing with my jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css, html

So I've a button which use ajax to send data to a php script. Also , I've a navigation bar whose background changes as I scroll down. The only problem here is that , once I have scrolled down to a point (after which the navigation bar background changes) and then I click the button. The location.reload() obviously refreshes the page , hence bringing back the original colour of the navigation bar.Not that the jQuery scroll-triggers-navigation-background change doesn't work after that, but still the page refresh reverts the background of the navigation bar to it's original state(which stays until I scroll again.)

Here's my jQuery code for the nav bar:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log("Scroll at " + scroll);
        if (scroll > 500) {
            $(".navbar").css("background" , "linear-gradient(to right,#4776E6 ,#8E54E9)");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".navbar").css("background" , "linear-gradient(to right, #434343 ,#000000 ,#434343)");
        }
        })
      })

    </script>
```

The ajax code for the button :

```
cart.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#add_to_cart").attr("disabled", true).val('Adding to Cart');
        $.ajax({
            type: cart.attr('method'), // POST or GET
            url: cart.attr('action'),   // THE PHP PAGE 
            data: cart.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == "yes"){
                    alert("Event Added to Your Cart");
                    location.reload();
                }
                else{
                    alert(data);
                    $("#add_to_cart").attr("disabled", false).val('Participate');
                }
            },
        });
```

[Here's the link for the gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3o751P8TQKaKhRHPAA/giphy.gif)

Comment: try replicating the example into a snippet so that the issue could be observed more closely

Comment: Why would you have a location.reload in an ajax call. It is designed to NOT have to reload the page

Comment: Actually I left the details . Cause it would be cumbersome. So , it's an event page , and that page has a participate button. That button is used to add that event to the user's cart. Now, I can't remove location.reload() cause then the ajax won't work.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong - if you must you can store position and color in localStorage

Comment: @mplungjan I added my ajax code. Now , can you spot the problem?

Comment: Yes - I see a location.reload in an Ajax call. That is just WRONG. If you MUST reload the page, SUBMIT the form instead of ajaxing. If you need to remember position and you MUST reload then use localStorage or cookies

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181494/updating-site-content-after-an-ajax-call-without-a-page-reload and many more

Comment: Ok, so... you have an animation. The animation starts when you scroll. When you reload the page, the animation stops, because you haven't scrolled yet. Where's the problem? this all seems to make sense.

Comment: I'll add a gif to clear things up.

Comment: @KevinB https://media.giphy.com/media/3o751P8TQKaKhRHPAA/giphy.gif

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam https://media.giphy.com/media/3o751P8TQKaKhRHPAA/giphy.gif

Comment: yeah, no need for a gif. Your problem is rather simple. Either stop reloading, stop worrying about the animation, or add logic that enables the animation if it was running on a previous visit to that page.

Comment: Cause if I don't the things aren't added to the cart. I tried commenting it out. And then, the button doesn't work .

Comment: @KevinB Can ya suggest any jQuery edit for my code so that even after reloading the animation doesn't break ?

Comment: It's not breaking. It's doing exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: @KevinB after the alert box , the navigation abruptly reverts to it's orignal gradient. Yeah , after that the animation still works. But for a second there we're back with the black gradient nav bar. So that's what I meant by breaking. How do I fix that part?

Comment: I've already explained how you fix that part. I'm not going to write code for doing something i wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @KevinB "or add logic that enables the animation if it was running on a previous visit to that page." Can u explain this part please? How do I do this in jQuery ?

Comment: On animation start, set flag in location where it will exist after page reload. On page load, if flag is set, start animation. it's not difficult.

Comment: @KevinB Alright. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bottom line, ***don't*** reload the page on ajax success. According to your gif posted above, on reload after success, the button is no longer visible and instead text is displayed telling the user that the option has already been added to the cart. Where does this logic live? In the server side code or client side code?

Comment: And in reference to your comment above: _"I tried commenting it out. And the, the button doesn't work." - This is because you're disabling the button but only re-enabling it on failure (or the subsequent page reload). Add `$("#add_to_cart").prop("disabled", false)` as the last line in your `success` callback and the button will be will re-enabled. Also note that while `.attr()` works in this case `disabled` is really a property of the input element and should be changed using the more appropriate `.prop()` method.

Comment: @War10ck Server side.

Comment: There's your problem. You have two options then: **(1)** Remove the ajax and do a standard HTML form submit or **(2)** Move the logic that hides the button and displays the "Already added..." text to the JavaScript success callback portion of the ajax statement. Leave the server side logic in case of page reload though. However, this will execute identical logic when the item is successfully added to the cart without you having to execute the `location.reload();`...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just using `$(window).scroll(function(){`, try using this: `$(document).on('scroll ready', function(){`

Edit: The solution I'm suggesting will not only check when a user scrolls, but also when ready. Since you have an if statement checking to see if the window has been scrolled ">500", it will check the same when the page is reloaded.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It's a bit vague. You may want to expand what the change will do and how it will fix the OP's problem.

Comment: Think it's kind of self-explanatory, but I will add it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @FelixMichaelCervin I added scroll ready. The problem still lingers.

Comment: That's because you use "window". I forgot about that. Try changing `$(window)` to `$(document).on('scroll ready', ...)`.